# NullPointerException when using drawImage (With Slick2d)

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, slick2d

Have a bit of basic code put into the beginning of a game and have run into a bit of a hang with this nasty NullPointerException for no apparent reason.

Loader.java (main class)

```
public class Loader extends StateBasedGame {
public static final int menu = 0;
public static final int ingame = 1;

public Loader() {
    super("insertGameName");
    this.addState(new Menu(menu));
    this.addState(new Ingame(ingame));

}

public static void main(String args[]) throws SlickException {

    AppGameContainer gameContainer = new AppGameContainer(new Loader());
    gameContainer.setDisplayMode(rpg.Settings.WIDTH, rpg.Settings.HEIGHT, false);
    gameContainer.setVSync(true);
    try {
        gameContainer.start();
    } catch (SlickException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void initStatesList(GameContainer arg0) throws SlickException {
    this.getState(0).init(arg0, this);
    // this.getState(1).init(arg0, this);
    this.enterState(menu);
}
```

}

and Menu.java (Initial game state)

```
public class Menu extends BasicGameState {
Image logo;

public Menu(int menu) {
}

public void init(GameContainer arg0, StateBasedGame arg1) throws SlickException {
    logo = new Image("res/logo.png");
}

public void render(GameContainer arg0, StateBasedGame arg1, Graphics g) throws SlickException {
    g.setBackground(Color.red);
    g.drawImage(logo, 0, 0);
}

public void update(GameContainer arg0, StateBasedGame arg1, int arg2) throws SlickException {

}

public int getID() {

    return 0;
}
```

}

The NullPointerException is at Menu.java:23 (g.drawImage(logo, 0, 0);
I was under the impression that all of this code had been done correctly, so it surprised me when I found out otherwise.

Side note: When fiddling with the code a bit, I found that changing 'logo' in g.drawImage(logo,0,0) for 'newImage("res/logo.png")' stopped the NullPointerException, but doesn't show the image, only the blank red background.

Comment: Where is your logo.png located in your source/project folder?

Comment: Project name is "RPG v2", so Loader is "RPG v2/src/rpg/Loader.java", Menu is "RPG v2/src/rpg.states/Menu.java" and logo.png is "RPG v2/res/logo.png"

Comment: I am pretty sure your image is null when rendering it. So init is probably not called.

Comment: What's the error? Include the full message.

Answer (score -1):

your method

> render(GameContainer arg0, StateBasedGame arg1, Graphics g)

is not getting any Graphics object, that's why it is giving NullPointException when you are calling any method over `g`
because the variable it is assigned a null value.

find out where this method is called and see if the arguments passed are correct.

Comment: Wrong. The render method is provided by the gamestate itself, so the Graphics object is not null..